# Оптимизация SQL запроса с несколькими LEFT JOIN в PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

Есть запрос:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  nlevel(org.path),
  org.path,
  subpath(org.path,0,-1),
  org.id,
  name,
  org.children_counter,
  e.employee_id AS manager_employee_id,
  e.fio AS manager_fio,
  pos.position_id,
  pos.pos_name,
  to_char(pos.effective_start_date,'DD.MM.YYYY') AS effective_start_date,
  coalesce(to_char(pos.effective_end_date,'DD.MM.YYYY'), '') AS effective_end_date,
  pos.grade,
  pos.employed,
  man_pos.pos_name AS manager_pos_name,
  spvisor.fio,
  spvisor_pos.pos_name
 FROM org_struct AS org
 LEFT JOIN positions AS pos ON org.id = pos.org_id
 LEFT JOIN employees AS e ON org.manager_position_id = e.position_id AND e.activity = true AND NOT e.internal_by_worker
 LEFT JOIN positions AS man_pos ON org.manager_position_id = man_pos.position_id
 LEFT JOIN employees AS spvisor ON pos.position_id = spvisor.position_id AND spvisor.activity = true AND NOT spvisor.internal_by_worker AND NOT pos.managers_equality
 LEFT JOIN positions AS spvisor_pos ON spvisor_pos.position_id = spvisor.position_id

 WHERE path <@ '0' AND ( (nlevel(org.path) = nlevel('0')) OR (nlevel(org.path) - 1 = nlevel('0')) )
 ORDER BY nlevel(org.path), org.id;
```

Созданные индексы, которые на крохи ускоряют работу запроса:

```
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS positions_cover ON positions (position_id, pos_name);
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS positions_cover_1 ON positions_20200731t090000 (position_id, pos_name);
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS org_manager_position_id ON org_struct USING hash (manager_position_id);
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS org_manager_position_id_1 ON org_struct_20200731t090000 USING hash (manager_position_id);
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS employees_position_id ON employees USING hash (position_id);
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS employees_position_id_1 ON employees_20200731t090000 USING hash (position_id);
```

В запросе в условии `WHERE path <@ '0' AND ( (nlevel(org.path) = nlevel('0')) OR (nlevel(org.path) - 1 = nlevel('0')) ) ORDER BY nlevel(org.path), org.id;` вместо `'0'` может стоять любой необходимый `path` и вместо `nlevel(org.path)-1`  может быть `nlevel(org.path)-4` например.

Используется наследование таблиц, поэтому создаются индексы для дочерних таблиц.

Результат `explain analyse`:

```
Unique  (cost=9151760368251.44..9485933360431.67 rows=7426066492894 width=445) (actual time=2934.328..2934.364 rows=32 loops=1)
  ->  Sort  (cost=9151760368251.44..9170325534483.67 rows=7426066492894 width=445) (actual time=2934.327..2934.329 rows=32 loops=1)
"        Sort Key: (nlevel(org.path)), org.id, org.path, (subpath(org.path, 0, '-1'::integer)), org.name, org.children_counter, e.employee_id, e.fio, pos.position_id, pos.pos_name, (to_char(pos.effective_start_date, 'DD.MM.YYYY'::text)), (COALESCE(to_char(pos.effective_end_date, 'DD.MM.YYYY'::text), ''::text)), pos.grade, pos.employed, man_pos.pos_name, spvisor.fio, spvisor_pos.pos_name"
        Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 41kB
        ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=141953.05..76517052727.23 rows=7426066492894 width=445) (actual time=2926.233..2934.131 rows=32 loops=1)
              Join Filter: (NOT pos.managers_equality)
              Rows Removed by Join Filter: 16
              ->  Hash Right Join  (cost=141953.05..6355371.34 rows=466140267 width=291) (actual time=2926.199..2933.608 rows=32 loops=1)
                    Hash Cond: (pos.org_id = org.id)
                    ->  Append  (cost=0.00..2015.56 rows=37038 width=81) (actual time=0.047..11.617 rows=37037 loops=1)
                          ->  Seq Scan on positions pos  (cost=0.00..0.00 rows=1 width=1061) (actual time=0.007..0.007 rows=0 loops=1)
                          ->  Seq Scan on positions_20200731t090000 pos_1  (cost=0.00..1830.37 rows=37037 width=81) (actual time=0.038..8.183 rows=37037 loops=1)
                    ->  Hash  (cost=36745.28..36745.28 rows=2517102 width=214) (actual time=2895.757..2895.757 rows=4 loops=1)
                          Buckets: 65536  Batches: 64  Memory Usage: 512kB
                          ->  Hash Right Join  (cost=2206.01..36745.28 rows=2517102 width=214) (actual time=2882.075..2894.603 rows=4 loops=1)
                                Hash Cond: (e.position_id = org.manager_position_id)
                                ->  Append  (cost=0.00..1325.01 rows=34410 width=36) (actual time=0.040..9.456 rows=34393 loops=1)
                                      ->  Seq Scan on employees e  (cost=0.00..0.00 rows=1 width=524) (actual time=0.008..0.008 rows=0 loops=1)
                                            Filter: (activity AND (NOT internal_by_worker))
                                      ->  Seq Scan on employees_20200731t090000 e_1  (cost=0.00..1152.96 rows=34409 width=36) (actual time=0.030..6.676 rows=34393 loops=1)
                                            Filter: (activity AND (NOT internal_by_worker))
                                            Rows Removed by Filter: 3303
                                ->  Hash  (cost=2023.13..2023.13 rows=14630 width=186) (actual time=2881.988..2881.988 rows=4 loops=1)
                                      Buckets: 16384  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 129kB
                                      ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=0.00..2023.13 rows=14630 width=186) (actual time=2878.217..2881.974 rows=4 loops=1)
                                            ->  Append  (cost=0.00..1698.60 rows=79 width=142) (actual time=2878.159..2881.870 rows=4 loops=1)
                                                  ->  Seq Scan on org_struct org  (cost=0.00..0.00 rows=1 width=560) (actual time=0.012..0.012 rows=0 loops=1)
                                                        Filter: ((path <@ '0'::ltree) AND ((nlevel(path) = 1) OR ((nlevel(path) - 1) = 1)))
                                                  ->  Seq Scan on org_struct_20200731t090000 org_1  (cost=0.00..1698.20 rows=78 width=137) (actual time=2878.145..2881.853 rows=4 loops=1)
                                                        Filter: ((path <@ '0'::ltree) AND ((nlevel(path) = 1) OR ((nlevel(path) - 1) = 1)))
                                                        Rows Removed by Filter: 9164
                                            ->  Append  (cost=0.00..4.09 rows=2 width=47) (actual time=0.021..0.022 rows=0 loops=4)
                                                  ->  Seq Scan on positions man_pos  (cost=0.00..0.00 rows=1 width=520) (actual time=0.003..0.003 rows=0 loops=4)
                                                        Filter: (org.manager_position_id = position_id)
                                                  ->  Index Only Scan using positions_cover_1 on positions_20200731t090000 man_pos_1  (cost=0.41..4.08 rows=1 width=47) (actual time=0.013..0.013 rows=0 loops=4)
                                                        Index Cond: (position_id = org.manager_position_id)
                                                        Heap Fetches: 0
              ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=0.00..1.13 rows=370 width=75) (actual time=0.013..0.013 rows=1 loops=32)
                    ->  Append  (cost=0.00..0.13 rows=2 width=32) (actual time=0.007..0.008 rows=1 loops=32)
                          ->  Seq Scan on employees spvisor  (cost=0.00..0.00 rows=1 width=520) (actual time=0.000..0.000 rows=0 loops=32)
                                Filter: (activity AND (NOT internal_by_worker) AND (pos.position_id = position_id))
                          ->  Index Scan using employees_position_id_1 on employees_20200731t090000 spvisor_1  (cost=0.00..0.12 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=0.005..0.005 rows=1 loops=32)
                                Index Cond: (position_id = pos.position_id)
                                Filter: (activity AND (NOT internal_by_worker))
                    ->  Append  (cost=0.00..0.48 rows=2 width=47) (actual time=0.006..0.006 rows=1 loops=26)
                          ->  Seq Scan on positions spvisor_pos  (cost=0.00..0.00 rows=1 width=520) (actual time=0.000..0.000 rows=0 loops=26)
                                Filter: (position_id = spvisor.position_id)
                          ->  Index Only Scan using positions_cover_1 on positions_20200731t090000 spvisor_pos_1  (cost=0.41..0.47 rows=1 width=47) (actual time=0.004..0.004 rows=1 loops=26)
                                Index Cond: (position_id = spvisor.position_id)
                                Heap Fetches: 1
Planning Time: 2.121 ms
JIT:
  Functions: 62
"  Options: Inlining true, Optimization true, Expressions true, Deforming true"
"  Timing: Generation 28.331 ms, Inlining 32.580 ms, Optimization 1839.802 ms, Emission 1003.417 ms, Total 2904.130 ms"
Execution Time: 2963.485 ms
```

Запрос работает почти 3 секунды, добавление новых индексов не помогает. Пытался переписать запрос со слиянием таблиц из подзапроса. Как еще можно переписать запрос или добавить необходимый индекс? Главное условие, чтобы не было повторений и отсортировано по nlevel(org.path) - (уровень в дереве подчиненных организаций), org.id.
После добавления индексов

```
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS org_struct_path_gist_idx_1 ON org_struct_20200731t090000 USING GIST (path);
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS org_struct_path_nlevel_1 ON org_struct_20200731t090000 (nlevel(path));
```

план запроса следующий:

```
Unique  (cost=9151760368251.44..9485933360431.67 rows=7426066492894 width=445) (actual time=2524.638..2524.669 rows=32 loops=1)
"  Buffers: shared hit=3850, temp read=26 written=481"
  ->  Sort  (cost=9151760368251.44..9170325534483.67 rows=7426066492894 width=445) (actual time=2524.636..2524.639 rows=32 loops=1)
"        Sort Key: (nlevel(org.path)), org.id, org.path, (subpath(org.path, 0, '-1'::integer)), org.name, org.children_counter, e.employee_id, e.fio, pos.position_id, pos.pos_name, (to_char(pos.effective_start_date, 'DD.MM.YYYY'::text)), (COALESCE(to_char(pos.effective_end_date, 'DD.MM.YYYY'::text), ''::text)), pos.grade, pos.employed, man_pos.pos_name, spvisor.fio, spvisor_pos.pos_name"
        Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 41kB
"        Buffers: shared hit=3850, temp read=26 written=481"
        ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=141953.05..76517052727.23 rows=7426066492894 width=445) (actual time=2518.494..2524.434 rows=32 loops=1)
              Join Filter: (NOT pos.managers_equality)
              Rows Removed by Join Filter: 16
"              Buffers: shared hit=3850, temp read=26 written=481"
              ->  Hash Right Join  (cost=141953.05..6355371.34 rows=466140267 width=291) (actual time=2518.462..2523.973 rows=32 loops=1)
                    Hash Cond: (pos.org_id = org.id)
"                    Buffers: shared hit=3715, temp read=26 written=481"
                    ->  Append  (cost=0.00..2015.56 rows=37038 width=81) (actual time=0.039..12.641 rows=37037 loops=1)
                          Buffers: shared hit=1460
                          ->  Seq Scan on positions pos  (cost=0.00..0.00 rows=1 width=1061) (actual time=0.007..0.007 rows=0 loops=1)
                          ->  Seq Scan on positions_20200731t090000 pos_1  (cost=0.00..1830.37 rows=37037 width=81) (actual time=0.032..8.757 rows=37037 loops=1)
                                Buffers: shared hit=1460
                    ->  Hash  (cost=36745.28..36745.28 rows=2517102 width=214) (actual time=2485.630..2485.630 rows=4 loops=1)
                          Buckets: 65536  Batches: 64  Memory Usage: 512kB
                          Buffers: shared hit=2255
                          ->  Hash Right Join  (cost=2206.01..36745.28 rows=2517102 width=214) (actual time=2471.818..2485.328 rows=4 loops=1)
                                Hash Cond: (e.position_id = org.manager_position_id)
                                Buffers: shared hit=2255
                                ->  Append  (cost=0.00..1325.01 rows=34410 width=36) (actual time=0.029..9.942 rows=34393 loops=1)
                                      Buffers: shared hit=776
                                      ->  Seq Scan on employees e  (cost=0.00..0.00 rows=1 width=524) (actual time=0.007..0.007 rows=0 loops=1)
                                            Filter: (activity AND (NOT internal_by_worker))
                                      ->  Seq Scan on employees_20200731t090000 e_1  (cost=0.00..1152.96 rows=34409 width=36) (actual time=0.020..6.781 rows=34393 loops=1)
                                            Filter: (activity AND (NOT internal_by_worker))
                                            Rows Removed by Filter: 3303
                                            Buffers: shared hit=776
                                ->  Hash  (cost=2023.13..2023.13 rows=14630 width=186) (actual time=2471.739..2471.740 rows=4 loops=1)
                                      Buckets: 16384  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 129kB
                                      Buffers: shared hit=1479
                                      ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=0.00..2023.13 rows=14630 width=186) (actual time=2468.608..2471.730 rows=4 loops=1)
                                            Buffers: shared hit=1479
                                            ->  Append  (cost=0.00..1698.60 rows=79 width=142) (actual time=2468.561..2471.660 rows=4 loops=1)
                                                  Buffers: shared hit=1469
                                                  ->  Seq Scan on org_struct org  (cost=0.00..0.00 rows=1 width=560) (actual time=0.013..0.013 rows=0 loops=1)
                                                        Filter: ((path <@ '0'::ltree) AND ((nlevel(path) = 1) OR ((nlevel(path) - 1) = 1)))
                                                  ->  Seq Scan on org_struct_20200731t090000 org_1  (cost=0.00..1698.20 rows=78 width=137) (actual time=2468.544..2471.642 rows=4 loops=1)
                                                        Filter: ((path <@ '0'::ltree) AND ((nlevel(path) = 1) OR ((nlevel(path) - 1) = 1)))
                                                        Rows Removed by Filter: 9164
                                                        Buffers: shared hit=1469
                                            ->  Append  (cost=0.00..4.09 rows=2 width=47) (actual time=0.013..0.013 rows=0 loops=4)
                                                  Buffers: shared hit=10
                                                  ->  Seq Scan on positions man_pos  (cost=0.00..0.00 rows=1 width=520) (actual time=0.002..0.002 rows=0 loops=4)
                                                        Filter: (org.manager_position_id = position_id)
                                                  ->  Index Only Scan using positions_cover_1 on positions_20200731t090000 man_pos_1  (cost=0.41..4.08 rows=1 width=47) (actual time=0.007..0.007 rows=0 loops=4)
                                                        Index Cond: (position_id = org.manager_position_id)
                                                        Heap Fetches: 0
                                                        Buffers: shared hit=10
              ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=0.00..1.13 rows=370 width=75) (actual time=0.011..0.012 rows=1 loops=32)
                    Buffers: shared hit=135
                    ->  Append  (cost=0.00..0.13 rows=2 width=32) (actual time=0.006..0.006 rows=1 loops=32)
                          Buffers: shared hit=55
                          ->  Seq Scan on employees spvisor  (cost=0.00..0.00 rows=1 width=520) (actual time=0.000..0.000 rows=0 loops=32)
                                Filter: (activity AND (NOT internal_by_worker) AND (pos.position_id = position_id))
                          ->  Index Scan using employees_position_id_1 on employees_20200731t090000 spvisor_1  (cost=0.00..0.12 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=0.003..0.004 rows=1 loops=32)
                                Index Cond: (position_id = pos.position_id)
                                Filter: (activity AND (NOT internal_by_worker))
                                Buffers: shared hit=55
                    ->  Append  (cost=0.00..0.48 rows=2 width=47) (actual time=0.005..0.006 rows=1 loops=26)
                          Buffers: shared hit=80
                          ->  Seq Scan on positions spvisor_pos  (cost=0.00..0.00 rows=1 width=520) (actual time=0.000..0.000 rows=0 loops=26)
                                Filter: (position_id = spvisor.position_id)
                          ->  Index Only Scan using positions_cover_1 on positions_20200731t090000 spvisor_pos_1  (cost=0.41..0.47 rows=1 width=47) (actual time=0.004..0.004 rows=1 loops=26)
                                Index Cond: (position_id = spvisor.position_id)
                                Heap Fetches: 1
                                Buffers: shared hit=80
Planning Time: 2.479 ms
JIT:
  Functions: 62
"  Options: Inlining true, Optimization true, Expressions true, Deforming true"
"  Timing: Generation 27.421 ms, Inlining 28.490 ms, Optimization 1605.063 ms, Emission 833.284 ms, Total 2494.258 ms"
Execution Time: 2552.608 ms
```

Пример 'path': '0.123.2345', где 0, 123, 2345 id организаций, `nlevel(0.123.2345) = 3` стандартная функция ltree в postgres

Answer (score 1):

Из плана видно, что основная проблема в условии `path <@ '0' AND ( (nlevel(org.path) = nlevel('0')) OR (nlevel(org.path) - 1 = nlevel('0')) )`:

```
->  Seq Scan on org_struct_20200731t090000 org_1  (cost=0.00..1698.20 rows=78 width=137) (actual time=2878.145..2881.853 rows=4 loops=1)
    Filter: ((path <@ '0'::ltree) AND ((nlevel(path) = 1) OR ((nlevel(path) - 1) = 1)))
    Rows Removed by Filter: 9164
```

Тут видно, что это занимает 2881/2934 = 98% времени выполнения. Тут можно попробовать добавить два индекса:

1. операция `<@` умеет использовать GiST индекс: `CREATE INDEX org_struct_path_gist_idx ON org_struct USING GIST (path)`, если он окажется достаточно селективен.
2. для фильтрации по уровню может помочь функциональный индекс: `CREATE INDEX org_struct_path_nlevel ON org_struct (nlevel(path))`.

Комбинация этих индексов должна помочь. Для этой конкретной выборки так точно, так как селективность запроса очень хорошая - в данном случае выбрано 4 из 9164+4 записей. В общем случае - нужно тестировать.

Важно еще изменить условие, чтобы постгрес смог использовать функциональный индекс:

```
(nlevel(org.path) = nlevel('0')) OR (nlevel(org.path) - 1 = nlevel('0'))
```

Нужно заменить на

```
(nlevel(org.path) = nlevel('0')) OR (nlevel(org.path) = nlevel('0') + 1)
```

Т.е. выражение в сравнении поля, должно точно совпадать с тем, что указано в функциональном индексе, т.к. постгрес не может преобразовать `nlevel(path) - 1 = 0` в `nlevel(path) = 1`

Так же нужно понимать, что эти дополнительные индексы влияют на скорость вставки и изменения, а так же занимают место и на диске и в буферном кеше.

Так же, важно отметить, что реализация такого запроса ("выбрать узел и непосредственных детей") с использованием `ltree` не всегда хорошо работает
в плане производительности. Можно ценой небольшой денормализации сделать такую выборку гораздо быстрее (и не добавлять этих индексов). А именно, можно добавить поле типа `parent_org_id`, которое будет хранить идентификатор родительского узла. Далее, добавить по нему индекс и заменить предикат по `path` (который сейчас работает медленно и требует дополнительных индексов) на `org.id = <org_id> or org.parent_org_id = <org_id>`. Это работает гораздо быстрее, потому что индекс гораздо меньше и эффективней, а значит есть больше шансов, что он будет в буферном кеше и не потребуется чтение с диска и т.д.

Comment: В чем может быть причина Seq Scan on org_struct_20200731t090000 при наличии этих индексов? ltree в данном случае используется потому, что предполагается выборка глубиной более 2 уровней вложенности. Да бы не делать запросы с рекурсией, используется `path`.

Comment: Видно, что по какой-то причине, все таки постгрес не использует индекс. В данном случае `org_struct_20200731t090000` неселективен, и главное это условие по `nlevel(path)`. Попробуйте изменить его на `(nlevel(org.path) = nlevel('0')) OR (nlevel(org.path) = nlevel('0') + 1)`. Еще может быть, что тут плохо планировщик работает изза наследования. Я бы попробовал, помогает ли если делать запрос только к дочерней таблице.

Comment: Я проверил, и действительно, постгрес не может преобразовать `nlevel(path) - 1 = 0` в `nlevel(path) = 1`, чтобы можно было использовать индекс. Так что нужно это сделать самому. Дополнил ответ.